# Failing to establish a session while trying to log into a website and opening the logged in page

Tags: perl, security, session-cookies, login-script, www-mechanize

I am new to Perl, so as an exercise I have been trying to log in to a web page and open the logged-in page later from the command line.

This is the code I wrote

```
use HTTP::Cookies;

use lib "/home/tivo/Desktop/exp/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW";
use Mechanize;

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());

$url = "<url>";

$mech->credentials('username' => 'password');
$mech->get($url);

$mech->save_content("logged_in.html");
```

After I execute the script, I try to open the saved HTML page using the command

```
$ firefox logged_in.html
```

But I get the error

> BIG-IP can not find session information in the request. This can happen because your browser restarted after an add-on was installed. If this occurred, click the link below to continue. This can also happen because cookies are disabled in your browser. If so, enable cookies in your browser and start a new session.

The same code worked for Facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the main issues

- You haven't installed `WWW::Mechanize`; it looks like you've just downloaded it and unpacked it, and added `use lib` to point to where it's unpacked. You need to run `cpan WWW::Mechanize` from the command line to install it properly, and then it will also be in a directory where Perl looks for libraries by default so there will be no need for a `use lib` at all
- You need to `use WWW::Mechanize`. Just `use Mechanize` won't do
- You must always start every Perl program with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`, and *declare* all your variables with `my`

Fixing those should get you a long way towards working

Comment: I tried to install the WWW::Mechanize package from the cpan command line, however it always failed. So, I downloaded the tar file to a local directory extracted it and installed it manually using the following commands MakeFile.PL, make, make test and make install. As for the the scope of variables, I am still experimenting with the code once it gets fixed I l add the use strict and use warnings @Borodin

Comment: Okay. I was waiting for you to post the "following commands"!

Comment: Sorry for that..I edited the comment..Take a look. @Borodin

Comment: In that case you have the module installed but you're still using the distribution package. Take out `use lib` altogether and fix `use WWW::Mechanize`. And you have it backwards for `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`: they will help you develop your program by revealing simple bugs in your code.

Comment: Okay..I will include the use strict and  use warnings and declare the variables as my. As for the fixing of use WWW::Mechanize, I am lost as I have tried all the possible ways to the best of my knowledge (which might be inadequate). Kindly suggest on how to proceed. @Borodin

Comment: It's very simple. Just `use WWW::Mechanize`. If that doesn't work then you haven't installed it properly.